# SQL query to match characters from N in X positions to characters from M in Y positions

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to figure out how to match characters based on position, but I also want the sub string to match to be based on position.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
    SELECT employee_table.LastFirst, employee_table.EmployeeId,
    MondayPlgReport.created_by,
        SUBSTR (employee_table.LastFirst, 0,5) AS employeeNameMatch
        SUBSTR (MondayPlgReport.created_by, 2,4) AS userNameMatch
    UPDATE MondayPlgReport
    SET MondayPlgReport.created_by=employee_table.EmployeeId
    WHERE employeeNameMatch=userNameMatch
```

I know that's wrong as hell, but hopefully it clarifies what I'm trying to achieve.

I also tried:

```
    SELECT LastFirst, EmployeeId,
      SUBSTR (LastFirst, 0,5) AS employeeNameMatch
    FROM employee_table

    SELECT created_by,
      SUBSTR (created_by, 2,4) AS userNameMatch
    FROM MondayPlgReport

    UPDATE MondayPlgReport
    SET MondayPlgReport.created_by=employee_table.EmployeeId
    WHERE employeeNameMatch=userNameMatch
```

When I run either

```
    SELECT LastFirst, EmployeeId,
      SUBSTR (LastFirst, 0,5) AS employeeNameMatch
    FROM employee_table
```

Or

```
    SELECT created_by,
      SUBSTR (created_by, 2,4) AS userNameMatch
    FROM MondayPlgReport
```

Then I do see the query returns the results I'm seeking. The issue here is that the employees change frequently, and I am seeking another position. If the code needs to be updated every time someone leaves or is hired, then it will be useless to the department as soon as I leave.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using mysql  you can use use JOIN   this way

```
UPDATE MondayPlgReport
JOIN mployee_table
SET MondayPlgReport.created_by=employee_table.EmployeeId
ON  SUBSTR(employee_table.LastFirst, 0,5)=SUBSTR(MondayPlgReport.created_by, 2,4)
```

and for sqlite

```
UPDATE MondayPlgReport
SET created_by = (select  EmployeeId 
                  from  employee_table 
                  where  SUBSTR(LastFirst, 0,5) = SUBSTR(MondayPlgReport.created_by, 2,4));
```

Comment: Thanks, @scaisEdge. Unfortunately it seems I don't have a choice but to use SQLite in portable apps for a number of reasons, and I get a near "." error when I tried the sqlite code you suggested.

I'm looking for an answer right now, but if you know that would also be cool and stuff.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense.

Thank you very much, @scaisEdge!